# Discord Voice Bot cannot play the audio file

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, discord, bots

I tried to write a bot that will join the voice channel and play a audio at 20:00.

Currently the bot joins the channel, but immediately after that it disconnects without making a single sound with this message:

`2023-04-07 17:58:01 INFO     discord.player ffmpeg process 18258 has not terminated. Waiting to terminate... 2023-04-07 17:58:01 INFO     discord.player ffmpeg process 18258 should have terminated with a return code of -9. 2023-04-07 17:58:01 INFO     discord.voice_client The voice handshake is being terminated for Channel ID 1093533451778523241 (Guild ID 1093533451778523237) 2023-04-07 17:58:01 INFO     discord.voice_client Disconnecting from voice normally, close code 1000. Audio file loaded: <discord.player.FFmpegPCMAudio object at 0x1021cca30> Audio could not be played:`

Code:

```
import discord
import asyncio
import datetime

TOKEN = 'TOKEN HERE' 
CHANNEL_ID = CHANNEL ID HERE

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())

async def play_sound(voice_client):
    try:
        source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('audio.mp3')
        print(f"Audio file loaded: {source}")
        voice_client.play(source)
        while voice_client.is_playing():
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Audio could not be played: {e}")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready')
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    target_time = datetime.time(hour=20, minute=00)
    if now.time() >= target_time:
        print(f"Current time: {now.time()}. Bot did not join channel.")
        return
    else:
        print(f"Current time: {now.time()}. Bot has joined at {target_time}.")
        await asyncio.sleep((datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), target_time) - now).total_seconds())
        channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
        if channel is not None:
            try:
                voice_client = await channel.connect()
                print(f'{client.user} joined voice chat.')
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
                await play_sound(voice_client)
                await voice_client.disconnect()
                print(f'{client.user} left voice chat.')
            except Exception as e:

                print(f"Error during joining channel : {e}")
        else:
            print(f"Did not find a channel of ID {CHANNEL_ID}.")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Any ideas?

ffmpeg has been installed properly.